# Nested arrays in Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

In the collection I'm working on, a document looks like this:

```
{
    name: 'Myname',
    other: 'other',
    stuff: [
        ['something', 12, 4, 'somethingelse'],
        ['morestuff', 2, 4, 8],
        ['finally', 12, 'again', 58],

    ]
}
```

I wrote this Mongoose schema to access it:

```
var MyDocSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    other: String,
    stuff: [],
});
```

When I query a doc, everything works well, the output shown in the console is right. But when, I try to do console.log(myDoc.stuff), I got the following:

```
['something', 12, 4, 'somethingelse', 'morestuff', 2, 4, 8, 'finally', 12, 'again', 58]
```

instead of

```
[
    ['something', 12, 4, 'somethingelse'],
    ['morestuff', 2, 4, 8],
    ['finally', 12, 'again', 58],

]
```

What am I doing wrong? Thank you for your help!!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

### Disclaimer: This response is pretty dated, 2012! It might not be the most accurate.

#### From the Mongoose documentation.

*http://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html: Scroll down to the Array section:*

> Note: specifying an empty array is equivalent to `[Mixed]`. The
>   following all create arrays of `Mixed`.

Details on what that means is in the Mixed section right above the Array section.

#### Here's what you need to do.

Define a schema for the embedded documents:

```
var Stuff = new Schema({
  name: String,
  value1: Number,
  ...
});
```

Use that instead of an empty array `[]`:

```
var MyDocSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  other: String,
  stuff: [Stuff],
});
```

Comment: Yes, it can work like this, thank you for your help. However, I also realized yesterday that despite the fact that the console output looks wrong, it can work as it. I can loop over myDoc.stuff and console.log(myDoc.stuff[0]) will ouput ['something', 12, 4, 'somethingelse'] as expected...

Comment: This works but is not a good practice. Mongoose schema is a wrapper to access data at the document level. The schema "Stuff" would have "save" and "update" etc methods on it which would not work in this way, rather would save at its own document level. Please correct me if I'm wrong because I would rather be wrong about this.

Comment: I am interested in what people think of Jason Sebring's thoughts on the use of sub-schemas here.

Comment: I agree, it doesn't seem to be the right way, at least for me. The update method isn't working the way I need it to. I need an array of arrays which contain numbers in them.

Comment: Can I also include a schema via `ref`? Like: `stuff: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'OtherStuff' }]`?

Comment: But required validation does not work for nested array of objects. any help would be appreciated