# mongoose array of array of strings

Tags: mongoose

I wish to have a Mongoose Schema property contain an array of array of strings, like so

```
[['one','two','three'],['four','five']]
```

How should I model this in my Schema? The following doesn't seem to work but it could possibly be another error...

```
names : [[{type: String, trim: true}]]
```

Do I have to make a seperate schema as per [Nested arrays in Mongoose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11342073/nested-arrays-in-mongoose)

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Ah, it turns out that nested arrays do have to be put in seperate schemas

```
var InnerArray = new mongoose.Schema({
  set : [{type: String, trim: true}]
})

var Stuff = new mongoose.Schema({
foo : [InnerArray]
})
```