# Mongoose schema , how to define an Array of Array object

Tags: node.js, mongoose

Is the following Mongoose schema correct ?

```
const TableSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  meta: {... },
  columns: [{...}],
  lines: [[Schema.Types.Mixed]]
});
```

using the following table

```
  let table1 = {
    meta: { ... },
    columns: [ { ... }, { ... } ],
    lines: [[12, 'Joe'], [14, 'John'], [6, 'Walter'], [3, 'William'], [18, 'Bill'], [22, 'Albert']]
  };
```

when I get and display the table, the lines array is empty :

```
table:  { 
_id: 5903113e80587e09bf39be34,
  __v: 0,
  lines: [],
  columns: 
   [ { _id: 5903113e80587e09bf39be36, ... },
     { _id: 5903113e80587e09bf39be35, ... } ],
  meta: 
   { name: 'TA-PRIV-123', ... }
}
```

**UPDATE 1**

I also tried

```
   const Line = new mongoose.Schema([Schema.Types.Mixed]);
   const TableSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
     ...
     lines: [Line]
   });
```

Comment: Have you tried defining a nested type as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14164860/1567923 ?

Comment: yes , see my update 1 .. no change

Comment: see my answer , sorry forgot to load the lines data .. so the output was empty..  your feedback is right , using a nested type as stated in my update runs well..

Answer (score 0):

solved

I forgot to add the lines in the previous POST request so the lines field was empty..
so Maxime feedback is right.. and my UPDATE 1 runs well