# How do I define a key named "type" in Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have a Schema definition with a nested object that looks like this:

```
mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    messages: [{
        type: String,
        message: String
    }]
});
```

Mongoose doesn't interpret this as I would like because there is a key named `type`, which conflicts with Mongoose's syntax for defining defaults, etc. Is there a way to define a key named "type"?

Comment: Trying to create a related model called `Message`, so that I can do `messages: [Message]`, per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11342073/nested-arrays-in-mongoose

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Oh, I remember this annoying problem, it took me ages to find out that the problem is that type is read by mongoose schema.

Just specify a `type:String` inside the type label

```
mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  messages: [{
    type: {type: String},
    message: String
  }]
});
```