# How use mongoose init model with array of array of object

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

i try to create model like below. My issue is how init array of array of object. Do like this

```
    var a = await new Model({user: "Tim", days:[{day: Date.now(), data : [{ hours: 100, type: "Ya" }]}]});
    await a.save();
```

Return error,

```
ValidationError: model validation failed: days.0.data.0: Cast to [string] failed for value "[ { hours: 100, type: 'Ya' } ]" (type string) at path "data.0"
```

So what`s the right way to create such model?

```
var SchemaChild = new Schema(
    {
        day: { type: Date },
        data: [{
            hours: Number,
            type: String,
        }]
    },
    { timestamps: true }
);

var SchemaParent = new Schema(
    {
        user: String,
        days: [SchemaChild]
    }
);
```

Comment: `Date.now()` will return number type timestamp, try `new Date()` for Date type.

Comment: Thanks for advice, but the result is same as above.

Comment: I think this is similar question [How do I define a key named "type" in Mongoose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22425917/how-do-i-define-a-key-named-type-in-mongoose), the problem is field name `type`,  try to declare like this `type: { type: String }`

Comment: turivishal, thank you very much, it`s work. You are right, now i realized that my declaration perceived like system reserved word